# Regex fails to match spaces at start of line

Tags: java, regex

I have the following unit test to check indentation at the start of lines of XML:

```
private static final String REGEX_PATTERN = "^\\s+";

@BeforeTest
@Parameters("unformattedXmlFile")
public void setup(String unformattedXmlFile) throws TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    EditXmlPanel panel = new EditXmlPanel();
    try {
        String unformatted = readFile(unformattedXmlFile);
        String formatter = panel.prettyFormat(unformatted);         
        String [] lines = formatter.split("\n");

        for(int i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(lines[i]);
            if(i !=0 && i !=lines.length -1) {                  
                //Assert.assertEquals((Character.isWhitespace(lines[i].charAt(0))), true);
                Assert.assertEquals(lines[i].matches(REGEX_PATTERN), true);
            }
        }           

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Assert.fail("Unable to read file: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

I read in an unformatted XML file - no indentation - then run it through a function to pretty print it, as in - indent it properly. My unit test then checks for indentation at the start of each line. So an indented line might look as follows:

```
         <message code="272" coeMsgName="CCR_I-Credit-Control-Initial" endtoend="AUTO" error="false" hopbyhop="AUTO" proxiable="true" request="true" retransmit="false">
```

My regex is:

```
^\\s+
```

So, match any number of spaces at the start  of the line. I have checked the pattern using regexr.com and it seems to be ok, but the assertion always fails. I can't see why.

Comment: Shouldn't your regex match the whole line, including the part after the indendation?

Comment: Little point for clarity:  Assert.assertEquals takes the expected value first, the actual second, so should be "Assert.assertEquals(true, lines[i].matches(REGEX_PATTERN));" ... or of course, you could jjust use assertTrue.

Comment: Javadoc for my assertEquals is:  `void org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(boolean actual, boolean expected)` - I am using testng, it's the opposite of junit... which is: `void org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual)` - slightly confusing it must be said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex must be:

```
private static final String REGEX_PATTERN = "\\s+.*";
```

since `String.matches` attempts to match full line with your regex otherwise it return false.

**PS:** Because of the same reason there is no need to use anchors `^` and `$` in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement: `lines[i].matches(REGEX_PATTERN)` you are matching `^\\s+` against the **whole** line.

So either your line is made of all spaces, or your assertion will fail.

You can either use a `Pattern` / `Matcher` idiom, or invoke `String.matches` with a broader pattern that will match the whole line.

See `String#matches` API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29).